# TestFlight Crash Reports

Tags: crash-reports, testflight

How does an app with TestFlight send its crash reports? Is there some immediate exception handler which sends the report? Or will the next start of the app trigger a scan through the crash logs and send pending ones?
Will also kills by the OS due to too much mem usage be sent as crash reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> An uncaught exception means that your application is in an unknown
>   state and there is not much that you can do but try and exit
>   gracefully. Our SDK does its best to get the data we collect in this
>   situation to you while it is crashing, but it is designed in such a
>   way that the important act of saving the data occurs in as safe way a
>   way as possible before trying to send anything. If you do use uncaught
>   exception or signal handlers install your handlers before calling
>   takeOff. Our SDK will then call your handler while ours is running

So it is sent immediately.

I would think that memory-triggered crashes would use the same method, but you never know if it will be able to complete.